# Compiling Libs for Android NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cross-compiling, .a, .lib

Android noob here.  I am trying to create an OpenGL ES based Android App that would run native code and I'm using CMake to build it.

Now I have a C++ library that I need to include, import and link(.a files) against the Android NDK code.  I understand the library needs to be cross compiled for Android, but would it work if I build just Linux binaries (.a files) instead, and link it with it?

Also, the C++ library is built using Windows platforms and CMake, which generates a .lib(static lib version of windows).  What's the best way to generate .a files from Windows platforms (static lib version of Linux from Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have a C++ library that I need to include, import and link(.a files) against the Android NDK code. I understand the library needs to be cross compiled for Android, but would it work if I build just Linux binaries (.a files) instead, and link it with it?

It wouldn't. This is because simply they are of different platforms. Both of them use same format(`.a`) but that does not mean they are compatible. For example, they use different standard libraries. So you must cross-compile it for Android.

> Also, the C++ library is built using Windows platforms and CMake, which generates a .lib(static lib version of windows). What's the best way to generate .a files from Windows platforms (static lib version of Linux from Windows)?

As your C++ library uses CMake and Android NDK officially support CMake build, this wouldn't be so hard.

You can [download Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) for Windows. Then try [CMake guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake). Basically what you should do is passing the toolchain file as a CMake argument(plus some arguments like ABI, API level, ...). So you don't need to edit your CMake file probably.